# Android sqliteOpenHelpers confliction while create a new table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have six sqliteOpenHelpers in my app, and I need to create a new Table. Normally, I create it in the onCreate() and onUpgrade(), plus the dbVerionCode.
It work well if I install it directly, but Table creates failed via Overinstall.None of the sqliteOpenHelpers' onUpgrade is called.

I've tried made a BaseSqliteOpenHelper and create the table in it，failed too.
I doubt is this a bug of Android, and with these six sqliteOpenHelpers, how can I create a new table?
`

```
public class BasePersistent extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public BasePersistent(Context context) {
    super(context, ConstC.DB_NAME_C, null, ConstC.VERSION_C);
  }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    IMEDBFactory.onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  LogUtilC.LogError("dbVersion:"+db.getVersion()+this.getClass().getName().toString());
    if (newVersion >= 7) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMETokenList ('userToken' TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,'sendMsgToken' TEXT ,'sendMsgTokenExpire' TEXT,'groupWriteToken' TEXT,'groupWriteTokenExpire' TEXT,'groupGetToken' TEXT,'groupGetTokenExpire' TEXT)");
    }
}



public class IMETokenPersistent extends BasePersistent {

public IMETokenPersistent(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    LogUtilC.LogError("dbVersion:" + db.getVersion() + this.getClass().getName().toString());
    if (newVersion >= 7) {
        //创建Token表
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMETokenList ('userToken' TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,'sendMsgToken' TEXT ,'sendMsgTokenExpire' TEXT,'groupWriteToken' TEXT,'groupWriteTokenExpire' TEXT,'groupGetToken' TEXT,'groupGetTokenExpire' TEXT)");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you drop old table?

Comment: Did you change your db version?

Comment: WHY ON EARTH are your field names enclosed in single quotes?!?!

Comment: Check  `ConstC.VERSION_C` has value greater then in previous release.

Comment: ConstC.VERSION_C need value 7 or more

Comment: thanks all above，I really did drop the old table and the VERSION_C is 8（the old Version is Six）. I've tried a simple demo within many sqliteHelpers in one app. It turns out that I have to do upgrade in the first SqliteHelper that's been used  or it will crash becausnde of the"table not foud".Still cann't found out what's wrong or been conflicted in this project.